# What is non-determinism in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

What do Haskell programmers mean when they refer to non-determinism? I read that list monads can be used to *model* non-determinism, but surely lists are not non-deterministic? What does it mean to model non-determinism? As far as I can fathom, this just means returning a set of all possible results for a set of calculations.

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638893/how-can-non-determinism-be-modeled-with-a-list-monad) might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. Nondeterminism as captured by the list monad indeed deals with computations (functions) that can return multiple possible results.

That is, a computation `f` that nondeterministically computes outputs of type `B` from inputs of type `A` is then in Haskell represented by a function that takes values of type `A` to *lists* of values of type `B`:

```
f :: A -> [B]
```

Then, if we also have computation `g` that—also nondeterministically—computes outputs of type `C` from inputs of type `B`,

```
g :: B -> [C]
```

we can compose these computations to obtain a combined computation `h` that takes inputs of type `A` to outputs of type `C`:

```
h :: A -> [C]
```

In Haskell, defining such a function `h` involves applying the function `g` to every possible result of the application `f x` and then flattening the thus obtained list of lists of possible outcomes for `h`:

```
h x = concat zs where zs = [g y | y <- f x]
```

It is this kind of composition that is captured by the list monad, allowing you to write:

```
h x = f x >>= g
```

or even

```
h = f >=> g
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I have not seen this so clearly explained elsewhere.