# Haskell How to generate all possible Palindromes

Tags: haskell, palindrome

how to generate all possible palindromes of the length `n`?

the only chars `['a'..'z']` should be used

```
palindrome n :: Integer -> [String]
```

Comment: What did you try? This looks as a problem dump.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: What part of the exercise are you having trouble with?

Comment: How would you generate all possible palindromes of length 0? length1? Given all possible palindromes of length `n - 2`, could you generate all possible palindromes of length `n`?

Comment: Perhaps an idea might be to generate first all palindromes with for instance length one, two and three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Even case

Lets for simplicity **first assume that `n` is even**, later we can generalize the function. We can use recursion for that. We define a helper function `pal' :: Integer -> [String] -> [String]`. Here the second argument, is the accumulated reverse string. So once we hit `0`, we simply have to emit a single list the contain the accumulated reversed string, like:

```
pal' 0 r = [r]
```

Given however we are still in the *generating* part of the palindrome, the left side thus, we can use list comprehension, like:

```
pal' k r = [ c : p | c <- ['a'..'z'], p <- pal' (k-1) (c:r) ]
```

So we iterate over `[a..z]` and for each such character, we we perform a recursive call on `pal'` where we need to generate an additional `k-1` characters, with `(c:r)` as reversed string to be emitted. Furthermore we yield for these palindromes `c : p`. We put thus the choses character in front of the palindrome.

So now for an `even_palindrome` function that generates **even** palindromes, we can write:

```
evenpalindrome :: Integer -> [String]
evenpalindrome n = pal' (div n 2) []
    where pal' 0 r = [r]
          pal' k r = [ c : p | c <- ['a'..'z'], p <- pal' (k-1) (c:r) ]
```

For testing purposes, I set the code to pick from the range `c <- ['a'..'d'], but you can set it to any range you want.

And if we generate palindromes for length 0, 2 and 4, we get:

```
*Main> evenpalindrome 0
[""]
*Main> evenpalindrome 2
["aa","bb","cc","dd"]
*Main> evenpalindrome 4
["aaaa","abba","acca","adda","baab","bbbb","bccb","bddb","caac","cbbc","cccc","cddc","daad","dbbd","dccd","dddd"]
```

So that seems to work. If we however write `evenpalindrome 1`, it will work in the sense that it will take integer division, and thus generate palindromes for length 0.

## Odd case

Now the question is what do we have to alter in order to let it work for **odd** length. There are two things that need to change here:

1. we need to generate an additional character, so we should not use `div n 2`, but `div (n+1) 2`; and
2. the last generated character should *not* be repeated in the reverse case.

So it means that we should first check `n` modulo 2 (let that be `d`), and then rewrite:

```
pal' 0 r = [drop (fromInteger d) r]
```

Furthermore as said before we should call the initial `pal'` with `pal' (div (n+1) 2) []`, so now the generalized version is:

```
palindrome :: Integer -> [String]
palindrome n = pal' (div (n+1) 2) []
    where pal' 0 r = [drop (fromInteger d) r]
          pal' k r = [ c : p | c <- ['a'..'z'], p <- pal' (k-1) (c:r) ]
          d = mod n 2
```

Which produces:

```
*Main> palindrome 1
["a","b","c","d"]
*Main> palindrome 2
["aa","bb","cc","dd"]
*Main> palindrome 3
["aaa","aba","aca","ada","bab","bbb","bcb","bdb","cac","cbc","ccc","cdc","dad","dbd","dcd","ddd"]
*Main> palindrome 4
["aaaa","abba","acca","adda","baab","bbbb","bccb","bddb","caac","cbbc","cccc","cddc","daad","dbbd","dccd","dddd"]
*Main> palindrome 5
["aaaaa","aabaa","aacaa","aadaa","ababa","abbba","abcba","abdba","acaca","acbca","accca","acdca","adada","adbda","adcda","addda","baaab","babab","bacab","badab","bbabb","bbbbb","bbcbb","bbdbb","bcacb","bcbcb","bcccb","bcdcb","bdadb","bdbdb","bdcdb","bdddb","caaac","cabac","cacac","cadac","cbabc","cbbbc","cbcbc","cbdbc","ccacc","ccbcc","ccccc","ccdcc","cdadc","cdbdc","cdcdc","cdddc","daaad","dabad","dacad","dadad","dbabd","dbbbd","dbcbd","dbdbd","dcacd","dcbcd","dcccd","dcdcd","ddadd","ddbdd","ddcdd","ddddd"]
```

## Memory structure

A nice thing about constructing the reverse part using recursion that way, is that the second half of all the palindromes is stored more efficiently. Given we generate palindromes of length 5 for the `['a'..'b'] range, the final list (after complete evaluation), will look like:

```
+---+
| o--- 'a' -- 'a' -> 'a' -\
+---+                      > 'a' -\
| o--> 'a' -> 'a' -> 'b' -/        \
+---+                               > 'a'
| o--> 'a' -> 'b' -> 'a' -\        /
+---+                      > 'b' -/
| o--> 'a' -> 'b' -> 'b' -/
+---+
| o--> 'b' -> 'a' -> 'a' -\
+---+                      > 'a' -\
| o--> 'b' -> 'a' -> 'b' -/        \
+---+                               > 'b'
| o--> 'b' -> 'b' -> 'a' -\        /
+---+                      > 'b' -/
| o--> 'b' -> 'b' -> 'b' -/
+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

A palindrome is a string where the last half of the characters are the reverse of the first half of the characters. Therefore, a simple algorithm would be to generate all strings of length `n / 2` and then append the reverse of each string to the end. For odd length palindromes, we can just drop the first character of the back half of the string, and make sure to round up when we find `n / 2`.

Now the tricky part is generating all the possible strings of length `n / 2`. We need to choose a character from `['a'..'z']` for each character in the string, and in Haskell, [lists can represent non-determinism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20638893/5743988). Therefore, all we need to do is use [`replicateM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) and it will create every string where each character is chosen non-deterministically from the alphabet.

A side note, the number of palindromes possible for any length `n` increases at an exponential rate. Using an `Integer` as the input is overkill, because the maximum value of an `Int` is already over 9 quintillion.

Here's one way to implement the full algorithm:

```
palindrome :: Int -> [String]
palindrome n
    | n < 0  = []
    | even n = map (\front -> front ++ reverse front) fronts
    | odd n  = map (\front -> front ++ tail (reverse front)) fronts
    where fronts = replicateM (div (n + 1) 2) ['a'..'z']
```